# Trying to load JavaScript only on pages within a PODS category/ custom post type

Tags: functions, pods-framework

I'd like to load CSS but only on certain pages.

This code normally works great but I cant figure out the 'Conditional Tag' what will only load these pages.

This is the function I place in my functions.php file:

```
//Below loads JS ONLY for the main directory pages
function directory_scripts () {
        if ( *** NOT SURE *** ):
            wp_enqueue_style(
            'addevent js',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/addevent.js',
            array()
        );
        endif;
 }

// add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'directory_scripts' );
```

What I do normally is look in the `<body>` tag to see what I can reference but it just doesn't want to work...

Here is my `<body>` info:

```
<body class="conference_2018-template-default single single-conference_2018 postid-3025 wp-custom-logo oceanwp-theme fullscreen-mobile no-header-border default-breakpoint has-sidebar content-right-sidebar has-topbar page-header-disabled has-breadcrumbs elementor-default ">
```

Is it because I am using PODS Custom Post WordPress Framework?

My URL structure is like this:

http:// wwebsite.com / directory / page-here

^ I am trying to place the JS in the above 'page-here' pages...

Thanks for all help

Comment: If the page slug is `page-here`, you can use `is_page( 'page-here' )`

Comment: Hi again! That would only work once for one page - problem is that I have hundreds of pages (of course with different URL's/ slugs) so I am trying to discover a 'directory' level or other that I can associate with that function.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `is_singular()` work:

> Returns true if the post_type is "foo".

```
if ( is_singular( 'foo' ) ) {
  //code
}
```

Another option would be `get_post_type()`:

> Retrieves the post type of the current post or of a given post.

```
if ( 'foo' == get_post_type() ) {
 //code
}
```

In the end it is all a matter of how you structured your site, which is not nearly clear enough. So you might be better off to distinguish via category, taxonomy related conditional tags. E.g. for [categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page), maybe like this exmaple from the codex:

```
if ( is_category( 5 ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( 5, get_query_var( 'cat' ) ) ) {
  //code
}
```

> Returns true when the category of posts being displayed is either term_id 5, or an ancestor of term_id 5 (subcategory, sub-subcategory...).

If you're actually trying to target sub-pages of a specific parent page, [`get_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/) might be an option. Exemplary:

```
if ( in_array( 123, get_ancestors( get_the_ID(), 'custom-post-type' ) ) {
  //code
}
```

This should get you a headstart, and give [Codex: Conditional Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) another good read. By the way, I'm answering on the assumption that PODS uses the WordPress API to achieve its functionality.